# Ncurses: Fails to write in previous window after next window is created

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I have created two Ncurses windows: Window 1 and Window 2.  I am able to write to Window 1 before Window 2 is called; however, after I call Window 2, I am unable to write to Window 1 using mvwprinw(window1, "Bla").  To illustrate:

```
...

initscr();
Window* window1 = newwin(10,10,0,0);
mvwprinw(window1, "i am writing to window");    // this works
wrefresh(window1);

Window* window2 = newwin(10,10, 12, 12);
mvwprintw(window2, "whee");             //works too
wrefresh(window2);

mvwprintw(window1, 0,0,"writing new sentence");     
// this does not show on the screen
wrefresh(window1);

...
```

Why is that so?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  Crashes?  Writes nothing?  Prints  your secret documents?  Also, your code looks fishy: the signature of mvwprintw doesn't match the documents I see: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwprintw

Comment: edited (:  It writes nothing, even after calling wrefresh().

Comment: Your code is still obviously broken, e.g. the typo in mvwprinw and the missing x, y parameters.  I'd say fix up your code before asking for help with it, because it's not in good shape now.  Too, the type is called WINDOW on my system rather than Window.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

If anyone encounters a similar problem, be aware of coding windows within multiple C++ classes.

A listener class was built within one of the classes.  However, it called an infinite loop (not an optimal way to design code, but sufficient for the program).

Hence, the code was stuck in the infinite loop, causing the next line of code to remain unexecuted.

SOLUTION: Use multithreading libs if necesary.